# Trying to create an ultrawide wallpaper with a gif

Tags: website-design, background, gif

I am trying to make a 3440x1440 wallpaper with a single gif. The result I am looking for is like from this website  http://girigiri.love/

You can see how the single gif fills up the entire screen in grids.
Any ideas? :D

Comment: please next time use the appropriate tags, I edited your question to reflect that

Comment: That is the most incredible thing I have ever seen...

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That site (who couldn't love it by the way?! haha). Is in reality simply repeating single images across its background.

For instance this frame:

[image]

Then you'd simply apply that with:

```
body {
 background-image: url("/img/your.gif");
}
```

No need to specify `background-repeat: repeat`, it's default.

That would fill the entire browser content area with copies of that image.

What they did on top of that is a bunch of JavaScript to change the background images as per a timing routine.

The JavaScript required is more a [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) question, so I'd be pleased to answer it over there :)

Comment: thank you! I will post in the appropriate section next time!

Comment: I couldn't love it. :P (I do like the song, but the graphic theme has the same effect on my optic nerve as diarrhoea has on my colon).

Comment: @Duane Dibbley haha yes me too! :)